# Say we have a presentation of a finite group. Does adding additional relations to the presentation always decrease the size of the group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, first-order-logic, group-presentation

It seems like it should, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

EDIT: I'm talking about nontrivial new relations here, i. e. ones that do not follow directly from the old ones.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "decrease". The size of the new group is certainly less than or equal to the size of the original, but it could be equal.

Comment: @Vik, yes; more generally, if the axiom of choice is assumed, then $|\Pi| \leq |X|$ for any set $X$ and any partitioning $\Pi$ of $X$.

Comment: Deciding if the new relation does not follow directly from the old ones can he highly nontrivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does (understanding decreasing as not strict):

Adding extra relations means taking a quotient of your original group $G$. That means that there exist a surjective map from your original group $G$ to the other one with extra relations, say $H$. Being $G$ and $H$ finite necessarily $|G| \geq |H|$.

Comment: Okay, but if there is a surjective map from G to a group of the same cardinality, since we're talking about finite groups it's a bijection and an isomorphism. Doesn't that mean that the new relations must be consequences of the old ones if they do not result in a strict decrease?

Comment: @Vik78 Well, yes. Think about what the sentence "the new relation is a consequence of the old ones" means.

Comment: To me it means that you can derive the new relations directly assuming nothing but the old ones.

Comment: @Vik78 "Well yes" is correct, but "think about what 'the new relation is a consequence of the old ones' means" is oversimplifying things.  There are two ways the new relation could be a consequence of the old ones: (i) the new relation is true in every group in which the old ones are, (ii) there is a proof of the new relation from the old ones. In fact (i) and (ii) are equivalent, but that's a theorem of logic, not just a "think about it" thing...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I meant to send that comment to you...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In one direction, (ii) clearly implies (i). Now let $G$ be a group, $R$ a set of relations, $N$ the normal subgroup generated by $R$, and $r$ another relation. Suppose (i) that "$r$ is true whenever $R$ is true". This means that if $N'$ is the normal subgroup of $G/N$ generated by $[r]$, any morphism $G/N \to H$ factors through $(G/N)/N' \to H$. By the Yoneda lemma, this is equivalent to the quotient map $G/N \to (G/N)/N'$ being an isomorphism; since $[r]$ is in the kernel of that map, $[r] = 0 \iff r \in N$. Now use the explicit description of $N$ in term of $R$ to get (ii).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Where was logic involved in the preceding proof? My logic skills are not great, but I guess you were talking about Gödel's completeness theorem...? But I don't really see how that's relevant here.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Well first, your comment is intricate enough that I think it's fair to say it's not just "think about what 'this is a consequence of that' means". Yes, II'm talking about Godel's incompletness theorem. The new version of my answer may clarify the relevance.  Regarding where logic was used in your proof: I don't know much group theory, but I suspect I could puzzle out most of what you said. Except for the last sentence "Now use the explicit description of $N$ in terms of $R$ to get (ii)". I don't see how that works at all.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well $N$ is the subgroup generated by all conjugates of elements of $R$. The fact that $r \in N$ means that $r = g_1 r_1^{\pm 1} g_1^{-1} \dots g_n r_n g_n^{\pm 1}$, where the $g_i \in G$ and $r_i \in R$. I think such an explicit expression counts as "$r$ follows directly from the old relations", or "there is a proof of $r$ given $R$". (My comment mostly looks intricate because I needed to stay under the character limit, I think it is actually rather straightforward... In particular the Yoneda lemma thing looks mysterious but was simply the shortest way to express the idea)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Got distracted trying to clean up my version... I think I can say what you're saying here in terms I can understand. We have a bunch of generators and relations. Say $F$ is the free group on the generators. Then $G=F/N$, where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by the relations. Saying a relation $R$ holds in $G$ is the same as saying $R$ is in $N$. And $N$ is the set of products of conjugates of the original relations (and their inverses). So yes, $R$ is a product of conjugates of the original relations, and yes that does say that $R$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. In case the "additional relations" are a consequence of the already existing ones in the presentation, the group remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's some not quite trivial mathematical logic that seems relevant here.

Say you have a presentation with a set of relations $S$, that give a group $G$. Say you add a new relation $R$. If the new set of relations defines the same group $G$ then it follows that every group satisfying $S$ also satisfies $R$, and now the Completeness Theorem from logic shows that yes, there is a proof of $R$ from $S$ and the axioms of group theory.

**Edit:** I've been asked to expand on this. Omitting details about the language containing a constant symbol for each generator in the presentation, etc.: Consider the relations in $S$ as sentences of the form "[some word in the generators]=$e$". Suppose there is no proof of $R$ from $A\cup S$, where $A$ is the set of axioms for group theory. Then the Completeness Theorem shows that there is a model $H$ of $A\cup S$ in which $R$ does not hold. In particular $H$ is a group, being a model of $A$. Let $H'$ be the subgroup of $H$ generated by (the interpretations of) the generators in the original presentation. Then $H'$ is a group in which $S$ holds but $R$ does not. And being generated by the original generators, $H'$ is a quotient of $G$. Hence $R$ does not hold in $G$.

Comment: This is the "right" answer, but I'd like to see you discuss the quotient. Also, maybe say why this is different than the linear algebra case of "linear dependence". :-)

Comment: @BBischof I believe I've "discussed the quotient", unless you meant something different. I don't know what you have in mind when you ask about a discussion of how this is different from linear independence. Presumably you want me to explain why [whatever] regarding linear algebra does not follow by the same argument, but I can't figure out what [whatever] you have in mind...

Comment: happy with your discussion of quotient. What I meant by comparing to linear algebra was why we can reduce the question of "consequence of other relations" to a statement of linearity(because of bases, essentially).

Comment: @BBischof Having expanded on what I wrote I've realized it's nonsense, for example the models of $A\cup S$ are not all quotients of $G$. I know there must be a correct argument along these lines, but I'm getting confused - the models of $A\cup S$ have exactly what to do with $G$? If you posted a correct version of all this I could just delete my answer...

Comment: I'll see if I have some time. I don't think you're too far off. The original discussion of completeness is good.

Comment: @BBischof I need to go as well. When you have a chance let me know if the current version seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title question is that additional relations do not always decrease the size of the group. 
Take for example the finite group
$$
\langle a,b\ |\ aba^{-1}b^{-2}=a^{-2}b^{-1}ab=1 \rangle.
$$
Now adding any new relations in $a$ and $b$ will not decrease the size of the group. Of course, the relations will follow from the "old" ones, because the group in question here is trivial, and one cannot decrease its size.

Comment: If it follows from the old relations that the group is trivial, how are the new ones not consequences of the old ones?